# STDIN.gets doesn't work as expected

Tags: ruby, io

I am trying to read from STDIN in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

STDIN.gets do |line|
  puts "line = #{line}"
end
```

It doesn't work for me.  I am not able to understand why.  My Ruby version is 2.1.8.

Comment: what error are you  getting?

Comment: I'm not aware of a version of `IO#gets` that takes a block. Is the fact that your `"line = #{line}"` doesn't work what you consider an error?

Comment: @dodecaphonic, It doesn't throw any error.  However, it terminates after reading the first line of input and doesn't execute the code inside the block.

Comment: That's because the block is being ignored, as `gets` doesn't take one. Try assigning to a variable like whodini9 showed below.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done like this

```
line = STDIN.gets.chomp
puts "line = #{line}"
```

If you want to run it continuously, you could so something like this:

```
def get_line
    line = STDIN.gets.chomp
    puts "line = #{line}"
end

while var == true
    get_line
end
```